# About attempting to sync audio and video

Tags: c, audio, video, sdl-2

I've got a little side project going on using SDL2/SDL_mixer and a couple other sound libraries. I've been trying for a while now to synchronize my audio and video but haven't been able to get it anywhere near successfully. All new to this stuff so forgive the poorman's logic and coding. At first I thought to set the delay to SDL_Delay(30) after every frame, and then a few other numbers in that range. Not quite right. Then I tried doing it by getting Ticks. Where I would get the difference between current_ticks and last_ticks and set a delay if the delta between ticks was <=30 and set the delay to 30-delta. Still not quite right (by far). Hoping someone on here with more experience might guide me in the right direction. In regards to the video, it's a visualizer of course, seems like a popular beginners project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic way you synchronize audio and video is that you choose one to use as a timer source and present the other according to that timer. The easiest is generally audio, but because it's generally buffered ahead, you need some method of measuring what time in the audio stream is actually coming out of the speakers. Once you get that, it's just a matter of waiting until the audio reaches the right time for the next video frame and displaying it.

Comment: Any idea how this would be done with the SDL audio API? You fill in a buffer so can't see how you'd know the amount buffered or current position?

Comment: @paulm: Look how mplayer's ao_sdl module does it.

Comment: Can't see any syncing in https://github.com/skypher/mplayer2/blob/master/libao2/ao_sdl.c ?

Comment: It's possible than that the SSL "pull" approach just avoids ever having noticeable buffering and only calls your callback just before the audio is needed. I don't know. You should probably ask a new question about how to determine audio buffering depth in the SDL API.